# Custom Logback Appender - Prepending file header and making it rollover

Tags: layout, logback, appender, rollingfileappender

The functionality that I need is **writing a header line** at the beginning of the configured log file. The log file should, in addition, **get rolled over** based on a time pattern (I'm talking logback 1.0.7).

So, I'm thinking of writing an **Appender** - although I'm not sure whether it's not a custom **Layout** that I actually need.

*1) Appender*

Per logback's documentation, the right approach is to extend `AppenderSkeleton`, but then how would I combine this with the `RollingFileAppender` (to make the file rollover?)

On the other hand, if I extend `RollingFileAppender`, what method do I override to just decorate the existing functionality? How do I tell it to write that particular String only at the beginning of the file?

*2) Layout*

Analogously, the approach seems to be extending `LayoutBase`, and providing an implementation for `doLayout(ILoggingEvent event)`. 
But again, I don't know how to just decorate the behaviour - just adding a new line in the file, rather than disrupting its functionality (because I still want the rest of the logs to show up properly).

The `getFileHeader()` in `LayoutBase` looks promising, but how do I use it? Is it even intended to be overridden by custom layouts? (probably yes, since it's part of the Layout interface, but then how?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here I am answering my own question, just in case someone else comes across the same problem. 
This is how I eventually did it (don't know however if it's the orthodox way):

Instead of extending AppenderSkeleton, I extended RollingFileAppender (to keep the rollover functionality), and overrode its openFile() method. In here I could manipulate the log file and write the header in it, after letting it do whatever it needed to do by default. Like this:

```
 public void openFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        super.openFile(fileName);
        File activeFile = new File(getFile());
        if (activeFile.exists() && activeFile.isFile() && activeFile.length() == 0) {
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(activeFile, header);
        }
  }
```

I configured the header in logback.xml, as simple as this: `<header> value </header>`. This injects it in the header field of my new appender.

Seems to work without problems, but please do post if you know a better way!

Comment: @teo do you know how can we get custom property defined in logback.xml in start method of any custom Appender class ?

Answer (score 5):

Your solution has a problem: it deletes the first line of log of each new file. I think this is because you write the header whereas the file is open by logback.
I've found another solution that does not have this problem:

```
public void openFile(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    super.openFile(fileName);
    File activeFile = new File(getFile());
    if (activeFile.exists() && activeFile.isFile() && activeFile.length() == 0)
    {
        lock.lock();
        try
        {
            new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), true).println("your header");
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```